# how to use octree to find 3d point intersection?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, intersection, octree

i am trying to use an octree to find fast intersection between a volume of interest and several curves in 3d space, similar to what you see here at 0:25

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL2AjQ4XEn4&t=119s

basically, i want to be able to quickly detect which curves intersect my volume of interest, which in my case is a sphere. so i want to avoid looping over all the points in each curve, to check the distance from the sphere which takes too long for a real time application.

can anyone give me the basic call structure to an octree that would be used to accomplish this? i know an octree is the correct data structure, i'm just not sure how to use it to accomplish this task.

thanks

Comment: Seems like Fibernavigator actually uses a [k-D tree](https://code.google.com/archive/p/imn697-fibernavigator/source/default/source?page=6).

Comment: Find in github.